# How to check if user is focusing from a particular element to another element with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I check if a user is focusing out of a particular element to another particular element? Something like this:

```
// If focusing out of inputA to inputB
if ($("#inputA").focusingTo("#inputB")) {
  // do something
}
```

Comment: You'd keep a list of instances where focus falls on the two elements, and then check whether the previous element was A when focusing on B. However, this doesn't eliminate the possibility that some other element was focused in between. You'd have to track focus to every relevant element in the document.

Comment: Maybe describe your overall goal and seek alternative solutions.

Comment: can't you just listen for a `blur` event on `#inputA` and then in the handler check `if ($("#inputB").is(":focus"))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to do the checks you want inside this handler.
Notice the class allows you to attach this only to the elements you want.

```js
var previousFocus = null;

$('.monitored').focus(function() {
  var previous = previousFocus ? 'object '+previousFocus : 'nowhere';
  console.log('focused on ' + this.id + ' coming from ' + previous);
  previousFocus = this.id;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div>
  <input class="monitored" id="inputA" name="inputA" value="inputA" />
</div>

<div >
  <input class="monitored" id="inputB" name="inputB" value="inputB" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// When focus A
$('#inputA').focus(function() {
    // if the mouse is over 'B' then show #message
    $('#inputB').mouseover(function() {
     // action
     $('#message').removeClass('hidden');
    });
    // else hide #message
    $('#inputB').mouseleave(function() {
     // action
     $('#message').addClass('hidden');
    });
});

// if 'A' loses focus
$('#inputA').blur(function() {
     // Clear Listeners
     $("#inputB").off("mouseover").off('mouseleave');
     $('#message').addClass('hidden');
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div>
  <input id="inputA" name="inputA" value="inputA" />
  <span id="message" class="hidden">on B</span>
</div>

<div >
  <input id="inputB" name="inputB" value="inputB" />
</div>
```